# Running Docker container randomly disappears on AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running Docker on a t2.micro AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu.
I'm running several containers. One of my long-running containers (always the same) just disappeared after running about 2-5 days for the third time right now. It is just gone with no sign of a crash.

- The machine has not been restarted (`uptime` says 15 days).
- I do not use the `--rm` flag: `docker run -d --name mycontainer myimage`.
- There is no exited zombie of this container when running `docker ps -a`.
- There is no log, i.e. `docker logs mycontainer` does not find any container.
- There is no log entry in `journalctl -u docker.service` within the time frame 
  where the container disappears. However, there are some other log entries 
  regarding another container (let's call it `othercontainer`) which are 
  occuring repeatedly about every 6 minutes (it's a cronjob, don't know if relevant):

  - `could not remove cluster networks: This node is not a swarm manager. Use 
    "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm 
    and try again`
  - `Handler for GET /v1.24/networks/othercontainer_default returned error: 
    network othercontainer_default not found`
  - `Firewalld running: false`

Even if there would be e.g. an out-of-memory issue or if my application just exits, I would still have an exited Docker container zombie in the `ps -a` overview, probably with exist status `0` or `!= 0`, right?
I also don't want to `--restart` automatically, I just want to see the exited container.
Where can I look for more details to trace the issue?

Versions:

- OS: `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` (Kernel: `4.4.0-1013-aws`)
- Docker: `Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e`

Comment: Are you using ECS? (Amazon ECS container agent 1.8.0 and later) Reduce the amount of time that stopped or exited containers remain on your container instances. The ECS_ENGINE_TASK_CLEANUP_WAIT_DURATION agent configuration variable sets the time duration to wait from when a task is stopped until the Docker container is removed (by default, this value is 3 hours). I would think there is a problem with the container, it stops and 3 hours later it's deleted?

Comment: Check the `dmesg` command output in your host

Comment: @lorenzvth7 I'm currently not using ECS, just simple EC2 instances, but I'm planning to mirgate everything soon.

@Robert Thank you for reminding me of `dmesg`. I could finally find out about a cronjob script which I think caused this problem (see answer). I just didn't expect that it was even possible on this way. Now I feel stupid to not check this part in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a hint to look at `dmesg` or maybe the general `journalctl` I think I finally found the issue.
Somehow, one of the cronjobs has been running `docker system prune -f` at its end every 5 minutes. This command basically seems to remove everything unused and non-running.

I didn't know about this command before but certainly this has to be the way how my exited containers got removed without me knowing how it happened.